# Energy of photon and charge

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, charge

What is the significance if any of the common energy value of the electron volt $(1.602 \times 10^{-19}$ joules), and the energy of a photon of wavelength $ \sim 1230$ nm (from the formula $E=h \nu$)?

Comment: The question is not clear. You can calculate the energy $E=h c / \lambda$ and convert it from Joule to eV units.Was this the question?

Comment: @DanielSank The rules for SI unit names which are spelled out is that they are in all lower case.  The unit of energy is the joule, not Joule.  The symbol, however, is capitalized in honor of the person, so the symbol for joule is J.  See the SI document, Section 5 here: https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf

Comment: @BillN Well I certainly learned something new today. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielSank You are welcome! And spread the word! :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no special significance to the fact that a photon of wavelength $1230\textrm{nm}$ has an energy of about an electron volt. After all the volt is an arbitrary choice of potential that happens to be convenient for us humans to use so likewise one electron volt is an arbitrary unit of energy.

Physically your $1230\textrm{nm}$ photon would be able to eject a photoelectron from a metal with a work function of $1\text{eV}$ or excite an electron between two energy levels separated by an energy of $1\textrm{eV}$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand charge as an 'energy', implied by the distribution of a real (unitary universal) force over a distance which is at once that of 'interior spatial depth', for point charge/electron, and capable of translation to real spatial distance, embodied in units of vector potential. This is motivated by finding that the product of the values for [h] and a light frequency v deriving from the same harmonically-defined basis approximate the value for 'charge e' derived similarly; allowing the relation of e and [h] by the FSC and measurable values. So you know. Thanks.

Comment: @jeremiah the value of $e$ derives from the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant), which is one of the fundamental constants that describe the universe.

Comment: Yes it is only because this geometric model (unitary universal field) suggests the basis for FSC in a geometric ratio central to its structure that e, h might be derived from it. Also, this model requires the idea of distribution of (cohesive) force to account for observable parameters, for charge q over a line in which the force acts. But q is inherently oscillatory, so determining Lagrangian (from potentials), always a function of the alternating dynamic of the unitary field, requires q to be fixed in some way.So charge e is implicit in the cubic geometry from which FSC arises.